# how to update a label text inside the tableview cell in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

UITableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath look like this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell Identifier";

  cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

  if(cell==nil)
  {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell   alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    UILabel *likelabelnew  =  [[UILabel alloc]init];

    likelabelnew.frame     =  CGRectMake(230,5,50,20);

    likelabelnew.text      =  @"old text";

    likelabelnew.tag=indexPath.row;

    [cell addSubview:likelabelnew];
  }

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to update the label ?

Comment: i have a button in the table view as  UIImage *LikeButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Heart_20.png"];
        Likebutton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 5, 20, 20);
        Likebutton.tag=indexPath.row;
        [Likebutton setImage:LikeButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Likebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(likebuttontapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:Likebutton];

Comment: in the likebuttontapped event i want to update the label

Comment: -(void)likebuttontapped:(UIButton *)sender 
{      likelabelnew.text=@"HI";  }

Comment: in the likebuttontapped event .. it gets working for the last cell label. i want it for the current cell which i tapped.

Comment: long row=[sender tag];
    NSLog(@"Like button tapped");
    NSLog(@"like button index, %ld",[sender tag]);
    Likebutton=(id)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[sender tag] inSection:0];

Comment: i already got the index path .. but unable to update the label for the current cell.

Comment: you can try my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code whereever you want to update your cell text. Suppose you have to update UILabel with tag 100 . Then add one more check :

```
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  NSArray *subviews = cell.subviews;
  for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] && subview.tag == 100) {
      UILabel *mylabel = (UILabel *)subview;
      //Update your lable here
    }
  }
```

Comment: Oh god. i have two label in every cell. i want it for only one label. what i want to do now

Comment: Then give some tag to label and add another condition for checking tag

Comment: sorry how can i check .. am not clear. i already given tag to label. please explain me in clear.

Comment: The subview.tag should be equal to indexPath.row

Comment: yes its working for all cells but not for the first cell. i dont know why i am checking in console.  Both labels are changing in the first cell only.

Comment: Ya. I got it finally . It is the mistake of tag. i added label.tag=[indexpath.row]+100; And in the updating method used as subview.tag=[indexpath row]+100; its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

First of all you don't need to add custom UILabel in the function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Then do this where you want to update your label.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UILabel *label = cell.textLabel;

label.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,230,31);
label.text = @"Your text";
```